# Livewire multi select form data

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using laravel 8 and needs to get data selected from a form selected data and insert only Clinic_id and Service_id on my ServClinic table
here is my models
needs to save data from a many to many relationship and get data further
my Clinic Model

```
<?php
class Clinic extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "clinics";

    public function services(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ServiceData::class,'serv_clinics');
    }
}
```

and
My serviceData Model

```
<?php
class ServiceData extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $tabel = "service_data";
    public function clinic(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class,'serv_clinics');
    }
}
```

and
ServeClinic Model

```
<?php
class ServClinic extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $tabel ="serv_clinics";
}
```

and view is

```
<main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-4 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">اضافة خدمة بالعيادة</h1>
    </div>

    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
    @endif                  
    <form class="form-horizontal" wire:submit.prevent="storeServices"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اختار العيادة</label><br/>
            <div class="col-md-4" wire:ignore>
                <select class="sel_categories form-control" name="clinics[]">
                    @foreach($clinics as $clinic)
                        <option value="{{$clinic->id}}">{{$clinic->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اختارالخدمات</label><br/>
            <div class="col-md-4" wire:ignore>
                <select class="form-control" name="services[]" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($services as $service)
                        <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">حفظ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

needs to get clinic_id and serve_id and save it in ServClinic table
my migration file is

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('serv_clinics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('clinic_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('serve_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('serve_id')->references('id')->on('service_data')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in selec2 multiples element, I think you first must get this data and get the collection of clinic models to be attached to services

```
public $clinics = []; // or whatever is the property for clinics ids array
public $services = []; // property of serviceData ids array

public function storeServices()
{
   $clinicCollection = Clinic::whereIn('id',$clinics)->get();
   foreach($clinicCollection as $clinic) {
      $clinic->attach($services);
   }
}
```

if you follow the Laravel docs about the many-many intermediate table (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) you will see don't need the ServClinics model. Only create the migration for clinic_service_data intermediate table.

Of course, this is the simplest way for my point. Now, if you go on with your solution, then you can do it like:

```
public function storeServices()
{
   $clinicCollection = Clinic::whereIn('id',$clinics)->get();
   $servDataCollection = Servicedata::whereIn('id',$services)->get();
   foreach($clinicCollection as $clinic) {
      foreach($servDataCollection as $servData) {
         ServClinic::create([
             'clinic_id' => $clinic->id,
             'serve_id' => $servData->id
         ]);
      }
   }
}
```

And of course, instead foreach statements you can filter the collections

Comment: it seems that $clinics on $clinicCollection = Clinic::whereIn('id',$clinics)->get(); not defined

Comment: $clinics is the array property for the multiple selected values for clinic select element. How are you binding this to backend? any JS code? I'm assuming this are select2 elements

Comment: yes , i'm using  select2 and have the same error

Comment: can you post the script tag of it? also, do dd($clinics) into the method

Comment: @push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sel_categories').select2();
            $('.sel_categories').on('change',function(e){
                var data = $('.sel_categories').select2("val");
                @this.set('selected_categories',data);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush  that's my script tag

Comment: so the property is $selected_categories = [] not $clinics :)